# Issue on updating winforms label text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms application
I have a public class inside my form code behind with the following structure :

```
 public partial class Home : Form
 {
     public class AsynchronousSocketListener
     {
         public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
         {
           //Here I want to Update a labels text this waw :
           //label1.Text = currantRFID;
         }
     }
 }
```

I can not  access `lablel1` control inside the `ReadCallback()`  function and update It's text .
when I try to do that I get the following error :

```
Error 3 Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'SFTWindowApplications.Home' via nested type 'SFTWindowApplications.Home.AsynchronousSocketListener'
```

how can I access It and what is the best way to update It's text ? I mean is It better to update It `Asynchronously` or not ?

thx in advance .

Comment: Why can't you access it? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Simply when I type label1 It does not appear in the intelicense and It's  not accessible

Comment: restart your visual studio..

Comment: @Karamafrooz That does not mean that you can't access it. Just write it down and run it and you will see if there's something wrong with intellisense or your code.

Comment: @SANDEEP I did that several times It did not work

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I wrote it and tried to compile but got this error :

Comment: Error 3 Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'SFTWindowApplications.Home' via nested type 'SFTWindowApplications.Home.AsynchronousSocketListener'

Comment: AsynchronousSocketListener has no access to the label1 property, that resides in the Home class.

Comment: @HakanFahlstedt what's the solution then ?

Comment: You need to supply the nested class with a reference to the label or the outer Home class. e. g in a constructor as some answers indicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nested class (i.e. `AsynchronousSocketListener`) does not automagically have access to the non-static members of its outer type (i.e. `Home`).

Restarting your IDE will not change this.  IntelliSense is doing what it should - not listing a member of an outer type that is not in scope.

If you wish for the async listener to affect the form's label, an instance of `AsynchronousSocketListener` will need a reference to `label1`...

```
// Really this is just an example of how it could avoid the error you encountered -
// reality checked only by my cerebral compiler. :)
public partial class Home : Form
{
    // instance of the async socket listener to use
    private AsynchronousSocketListener asyncSocketListener; 

    public Home()
    {
        // Initialize the async socket listener, and provide to it a reference to
        // the label it should update.
        asyncSocketListener = new AsynchronousSocketListener(label1);
    }

    public class AsynchronousSocketListener
    {
        private Label targetLabel;

        public AsynchronousSocketListener(Label targetLabel)
        {
            this.targetLabel = targetLabel;
        }

        public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // // assuming currantRFID is part of the async result ar
            this.targetLabel.Text = ar.currantRFID;
        }
    }
}
```

..., or you need to take an event-driven approach.

Ideally the relationship between the classes and what happens following a response would be less concrete & rigid (e.g. not specific to just a label, not requiring the classes to know so much about each other).  An event-driven approach (i.e. the async listener raises an event to which this particular form subscribes and handles by updating its label) would achieve these goals.  But I am admittedly just trying to give you a sense how it could work with respect to the non-static member access that is at the center of the question you asked.

Comment: really thx for your code , but as I commented on Dannydust answear in my page load I  start a new thread and construct the class and when I tried his code which is similar to yours I get the bug : Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Comment: I've wondered in the back of my mind about a cross-thread issue coming from this as you commented on trying @Dannydust's sample code: an event-driven approach like I described would avoid this problem while decoupling the two classes.

Comment: @insomnium's suggestion in his comment on Dannydust's answer is another way to approach the cross-thread issue that followed trouble accessing a non-static member.

Comment: Search for information on C# events - defining & raising them (i.e in your async listener) and subscribing to & handling them (i.e. in your form that is using the async listener).  I am going to draw the line at simply addressing the issue at the center of your original question for tonight - access to a non-static member in an outer class.  If you get stuck using events, post a question with what you have tried, what is not working, and what you would like to know to help.

Answer (score 3):

It's a different class, so you need to pass the label instance or pass the Home class instance to the method and make the label public (imo it's protected by default).

**UPDATE**: New code with BackGroundWorker
Note: I didn't test this code, but it should give you an idea.

```
public partial class Home : Form
{
 public class AsynchronousSocketListener : IDisposable
 {
   private BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

   private Label myLabel;
   public AsynchronousSocketListener(Label lbl)
   {
       myLabel = lbl;
       worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerCompleted;
       worker.DoWork += DoWork;
       worker.RunWorkerAsync();
   }
   public void Dispose()
    {
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted -= WorkerCompleted;
        worker.CancelAsync();
        worker.Dispose();
    }

   private void DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
     // Perform your work on the other Thread
     e.Result = currantRFID;
   }

   public void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
   {
      //Here I want to Update a labels text this waw :
      myLabel.Text = args.Result;
   }
         }
}




/*

    public partial class Home : Form
     {
         public class AsynchronousSocketListener
         {
             private Label myLabel;
             public AsynchronousSocketListener(Label lbl)
             {
                myLabel = lbl;
             }
             public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
             {
               //Here I want to Update a labels text this waw :
               myLabel.Text = currantRFID;
             }
         }
     }

*/
```

Comment: I tried your code this bug is throwen : Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: this is when I construct that : private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                AsynchronousSocketListener asynchronousSocketListener = new AsynchronousSocketListener(label1);
                System.Threading.Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(asynchronousSocketListener.StartListening));
                t.Start();
            }

Comment: I thought you will get into this prooblem. You have to use a BackGroundworker instead of your class. The UI Thread (where your Label is) is in a different Thread and it's not possible to update it this way.

Comment: You can check 

`if(label1.InvokeRequired)
{
label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => label1.Text=""));
}`

Comment: if insomnium_ snippet is not working. Here is a good explanation of the Backgroundworker. 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your IDE, if it doesn't help, show the designer-code.

Comment: `-1` for the restart suggestion `+ +1` for the designer-code suggestion `= 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can't access member of one class inside other class without having any reference to parent class. You need to access `label1` inside `ReadCallback` through your Home class.

See [this example](http://ideone.com/n4CTHz)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your Home-Class to the classes where you want to use the controls, e.g.

> [...] new AsynchronousSocketListener(this)

and pass it until you are in the depth where you need it.